# Model driven form - pristine is always true

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

How can I programmatically set pristine to false?

`this.myForm.get('categories').set`.....set what? There is no setPristine.

For some reason when I set the categories like this:

```
        this.myForm.get('categories').setValue(
            this.multiselectFindCategory.selectedCategories
        );
```

`this.myForm.controls.categories.pristine` is still equal to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.myForm.get('categories').markAsDirty();
```